# Sticky scroll from cached images in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I an using this code to display some image inside a UICollectionView but lets say that the cells are 25. When i go down to the last cell and then i try to go up to the first the images are loading again (from cache but still it shows the loading indicator.
My phone is iPhone SE and i dont have many apps and the phone is running perfect. If i load my app to an older iphone with many data on it then the scrolling it becomes sticky and its very annoying. How can we avoid this happening inside the collections view function cell for item at index path ???

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("RecipesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecipesCell    
// Get Cover image
        let myCache = ImageCache(name: recipesClass.objectId!)
        let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
        let optionInfo: KingfisherOptionsInfo = [
            .DownloadPriority(0.5),
            .CallbackDispatchQueue(queue),
            .Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1)),
            .TargetCache(myCache)
        ]
        if  let imageFile = recipesClass[RECIPES_COVER] as? PFFile {

        let URL = NSURL(string: imageFile.url!)!

        cell.coverImage.kf_setImageWithURL(URL, placeholderImage: nil,
            optionsInfo: optionInfo,
            progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
                print("\(indexPath.row + 1): \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
            },
            completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                print("\(indexPath.row + 1): Finished")
                print("cacheType: \(cacheType) \(indexPath.row + 1): Finished")
        })

        } else {
             cell.coverImage.image = UIImage(named:"logo")
        }
```

Does anyone has the same issue?
Thanks!

FYI I'm using parse and kingfisher for caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research about UI Kit and analyzing my app with Instruments > Time Profiler i figured out that `image decoding` is being executed on the main thread. Which is bad practise. So `Kingfisher` has an option which decodes the images on the background and my app went a lot faster on old iphones but still was a bit sticky. So I took off the rounded corners on the cell and enabled paging so it will slow down the scroll and it is great now.

For the background image decode i used this

```
   let optionInfo: KingfisherOptionsInfo = [
            .DownloadPriority(0.5),
            .CallbackDispatchQueue(queue),
            .Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1)),
            .TargetCache(myCache),
            .BackgroundDecode //this is the new option I added
        ]
```